# confused by Python set initialization

Tags: python

Sometimes see code like below, and did some debugging, but still confused. Wondering whether it is initialized as a list of set()? A list of set(), and each element in a set is also a list? Post what I see in PyCharm and appreciate anyone could help to explain what the grammar mean, and how to read such line of code.

```
table = [set() for i in range(10)]
```

[image]

regards,
Lin

Comment: It's a list of empty sets.

Comment: I don't know what PyCharm is up to, but `table` is just a `list` of ten empty `set`s.

Comment: If you're confused with the `[]` inside the sets, this indicates that the set is *empty*. Try `set()` in your Python shell.

Comment: I tried that and it just returns the `repr()` of an empty `set`: `set()`.

Comment: @MarounMaroun, thanks for the answer, yes, you are correct and [] inside Set showed by PyCharm is exactly why I am confused. Could you add a reply, and I will mark it as Answer so that it benefit other people as well.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, cool, this is exactly why I am confused.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, what do you mean repr()?

Comment: It is also exactly why I don't use anything more "helpful" than Notepad++. :P

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, good idea. But how do you debug Python script in NotePad++?

Comment: The `repr()` of an object should be the string you would enter into the interpreter (or `eval()`) to reproduce the object.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, thanks, could you show me the complete statement you are using with `repr` for this problem? Thanks.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, you have helped me to resolve this issue, if you could add a reply, I will mark it as answered so that it benefit other people as well from their search. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simply PyCharm's way of representing empty `set`s. The standard Python interpreter will instead use `set()`, as that is what you would enter into the interpreter to create an empty `set` and the consistency is helpful. Technically, `set([])` sends an empty `list` to the `set` built-in function, which results in an empty `set` object, but you can get the same result with simply `set()`. I don't know why PyCharm's developers decided to represent an empty set in a different way.

In a standard Python interpreter:

```
>>> set()
set()
>>> set([])
set()
```

`set([])` couldn't represent a `set` that contains an empty `list`, because `list` isn't a hashable type (and, as shown, that would be represented with `{[]}` anyway):

```
>>> {[]}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

If you want to know the reasoning behind this nonstandard representation, you'd have to ask PyCharm's developers.